# Handling InputMismatchException in a While-Loop

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, java.util.scanner

So I have a while-loop where you have 3 options to choose from and you choose them by inserting a number on standard input using a scanner, my code is like this:

```
    int option;
    String request;
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose an option:\n" + "1-Get camera information\n" + "2-Submit Data\n"
         + "3-Exit");
    while(true){
        try {
            option = input2.nextInt();
            if (option == 1) {
                System.out.println("Camera name:");
                request = input2.nextLine();
                while (request.length() < 3 || request.length() > 15) {
                    System.out.println("Name has to be between 3 and 15 characters, insert a new one:");
                    request = input2.nextLine();
                }
                CamInfoRequest info_request = CamInfoRequest.newBuilder().setName(request).build();
                if (stub.camInfo(info_request).getReturn() != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Camera does not exist");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(stub.camInfo(info_request).getLatitude() + " " + stub.camInfo(info_request).getLongitude());
                }
            } else if (option == 2) {
                System.out.println("submit");
            } else if(option ==3){
                break;
            } else{
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
            }
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
```

So the way this is the code enters in an infinite loop when it catches the exception where it keeps printing "Invalid input", I tried using input2.next() at the catch but then he waits for another input I don't want, I can't use input2.close() either. What can I do?

Comment: Your first mistake is using `while(true)`. Use a boolean flag instead. Would look like `while(exitLoop)` and then set `exitLoop = true` where you want to leave the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use input2.close() either.

You should never close the `Scanner` instance for `System.in` as it also closes the `System.in`.

> I tried using input2.next() at the catch but then he waits for another
>   input I don't want

Use `Scanner::nextLine` instead of `Scanner::next`, `Scanner::nextInt` etc. Check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) to learn why.

Also, try to use `do...while` wherever you need to ask the user to enter the data again in case of an invalid entry.

Given below is a sample code incorporating these points:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int option;
        boolean valid;
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("Choose an option:\n" + "1-Get camera information\n" + "2-Submit Data\n" + "3-Exit");
            try {
                option = Integer.parseInt(input2.nextLine());
                if (option < 1 || option > 3) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                // ...Place here the rest of code (which is based on the value of option)
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("This is an invalid entry. Please try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Choose an option:
1-Get camera information
2-Submit Data
3-Exit
abc
This is an invalid entry. Please try again.
Choose an option:
1-Get camera information
2-Submit Data
3-Exit
6
This is an invalid entry. Please try again.
Choose an option:
1-Get camera information
2-Submit Data
3-Exit
2
```

Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put the Scanner statement inside your try block

```
while (true) {
            try {
                Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                option = input2.nextInt();
                if (option == 1) {
```

Comment: The infinite printing stops that way, the problem is that imagine I start the loop, choose an invalid input and then I choose option 1, it immediately enters in the while and prints "Name has to be between 3 and 15 characters, insert a new one:" before I can even write something

Comment: Try using request = input2.next(); instead of request = input2.nextLine();